# How to filter a collection of objects by field value?

Tags: python, sortedlist, bisect, sortedcollection, itertools-groupby

How in Python to organize and filter a collection of objects by a field value? I need to filter by being equal to an exact value and by being less than a value.

And how to do it effectively? If I store my objects in a list I need to iterate over a whole list, potentially holding hundreds of thousands of objects.

```
@dataclass
class Person:
  name: str
  salary: float
  is_boss: bool


# if to store objects in a list...
collection = [Person("Jack", 50000, 0), ..., Person("Jane", 120000, 1)]

# filtering in O(n), sloooooow
target = 100000
filtered_collection = [x for x in collection if salary < target]
```

PS: Actually my use case is **group by** by a certain field, i.e. `is_boss` and filter by another, i.e. `salary`. How to do that? Should I user `itertools.groupby` over sorted lists and make my objects comparable?

Comment: If your `list` doesn't have an structure, then yeah, you'll have to check them all. You're going to need to be much more specific about your use case if you want improvements beyond `O(n)` filtering passes. `equals_target = [x for x in y if x.field == target]` is the straightforward approach, but that's trivial, and no savings (big-O-wise) over naive solutions involving regular `for` loops.

Comment: Can you provide and example/sample data & sample output?

Comment: yes, I have a collection of objects, one of options to put them in a list

Comment: but I would filter only by the certain field, any options to organize my collection of object for faster filtering?

Comment: @Sengiley: There's a billion options. You need to be more specific on what your real problem is to get useful suggestions, ideally in the form of a [MCVE] of what you're doing now that's inadequate.

Comment: an example think of a collection of Employees and I need to filter by salary being less than equal some threshold

Comment: @Sengiley: An actual [MCVE] please. Edit the code into the question. I suspect, if you need to repeatedly filter by different target salaries, the answer will be maintaining a sorted `list` of the employees and using the `bisect` module to quickly find the slice index in question, but guessing at your goals from incredibly limited details is not easy.

Comment: yeah, I've got your point, added an code example

Comment: as for `bisect` can you also please provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you maintain your `list` in sorted order (which ideally means few insertions or removals, because mid-`list` insertion/removal is itself `O(n)`), you can find the set of `Person`s below a given salary with [the `bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html).

```
from bisect import bisect
from operator import attrgetter

# if to store objects in a list...
collection = [Person("Jack", 50000, 0), ..., Person("Jane", 120000, 1)]
collection.sort(key=attrgetter('salary'))  # O(n log n) initial sort

# filtering searches in O(log n):
target = 100000
filtered_collection = collection[:bisect(collection, target, key=attrgetter('salary'))]
```

Note: The `key` argument to the various `bisect` module functions is only supported as of 3.10. In prior versions, you'd need to define the rich comparison operators for `Person` in terms of `salary` and search for a faked out `Person` object, or maintain ugly separate sorted `list`s, one of `salary` alone, and a parallel `list` of the `Person` objects.

For adding individual elements to the `collection`, you could use `bisect`'s `insort` function. Or you could just add a bunch of items to the end of the `list` in bulk and resort it on the same `key` as before (Python's sorting algorithm, TimSort, gets near `O(n)` performance when the collection is mostly in order already, so the cost is not as high as you might think).

I'll note that in practice, this sort of scenario (massive data that can be arbitrarily ordered by multiple fields) usually calls for a database; you might consider [using `sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) (eventually switching to a more production-grade database like MySQL or PostGres if needed), which, with appropriate indexes defined, would let you do `O(log n)` `SELECT`s on any indexed field; you could convert to `Person` objects on extraction for the data you actually need to work with. The B-trees that true DBMS solutions provide get you `O(log n)` effort for inserts, deletes and selects on the index fields, where Python built-in collection types make you choose; only one of insertion/deletion or searching can be truly `O(log n)`, while the other is `O(n)`.

Comment: thanks! so I can to trade the time costs of creating and maintaining a list in sorted order for the speed up in search? what if I additionally want to filter by another field along with salary?

Comment: @Sengiley: You can `sort` by multiple fields (the `attrgetter` happily lets you pass multiple names to it), so if you want a backup comparison by `name` or the like that's possible (`key=attrgetter('salary', 'name')`). But if you need to sometimes filter by salary, and sometimes by name, sometimes by some other attribute, that's what true databases are for. No simple container type handles sorting the contents in many different ways simultaneously, but that's basically what databases are for.

Comment: and my use case is not a database, just a huge in-memory collection of objects

Comment: @Sengiley: Your use case can be *made* into a database. `sqlite3` supports purely in-memory databases (you just open `":memory:"` instead of a real file name). And if you need to select from that huge collection using many different criteria, you *want* a database.

Comment: yet, I thought something like B-trees but for Python's collections

Comment: and in no way I will use a database, this is a numeric code

Comment: your post it very insightful! can you please provide a code example of how to use `bisect` for maintaining and filtering object by two fields? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a sort method - All you have to do is create a function that detirmes if an object is greater than another object - let me show you

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(bar):
        this.bar = bar

fooArray = [Foo(10),Foo(8),Foo(9)]
def sortFoo(foo):
    return foo.bar

fooArray.sort(key=sortFoo)
```

Comment: Nitpicks: There's no need for `sortFoo`; either `fooArray.sort(key=lamba x: x.bar)` or (with `from operator import attrgetter` at the top of the file) `fooArray.sort(key=attrgetter('bar'))` would be the typical ways to do simple attribute retrieval for the key in this case. PEP8 naming never uses `mixedCase`, everything you named with `mixedCase` should be `lowercase` or `lowercase_with_underscores`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm numeric programmer mostly using numpy arrays, and wondering how to effectively maintain and sort a collection of object

I think an ideal example will include some built-in objects methods like __eq__ or __lt__ and some advanced data structures like trees for example? I'm afraid that storing objects in a list for my purpose is ineffective